# How to trash app file with pathname too long after failed app build - Xcode 12 new build system with MacOS 11.5.2

Tags: macos-big-sur, xcode12

I have files in trash that I can't delete with an error that the pathname is too long. How can I get rid of those?

Where these files came from: I was getting Xcode 12 build failures after switching over to new build system with a plist too long error; stackoverflow helped with that -- the problem was that somehow the Product target (the app) was marked as included in the target, thereby recursively creating a giant path for the app. So unchecking the box allowed the build to complete. Thanks everybody!!

However, in the fray, I frequently cleaned the Build folder or trashed the Derived Data folder. Now I have a bunch of zero-length files for the app in the trash; emptying the trash fails with an error that it can't delete the app file because the pathname is too long. Nothing else got deleted from Trash either.

Any suggestions of how to get these cleaned up?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to clean up the bad app files, but I have no idea why it worked. Note that the app icons were greyed out with a "stop" icon throughout. I decided I would clean up as much as possible, so I dragged all of the current contents of Trash (the many Derived Data & Build folders) into another desktop folder, and moved everything that wasn't a bad app file back into Trash, and emptied Trash. I left each app file in its immediate enclosing folders. Then I tried to consolidate the remaining bad app files into as few folders as possible, and along the way I discovered that I could force a replacement of one bad app file with another (just dragging it into the other's folder). So I got down to only one bad file. Then I tried moving it Trash, and bang - I could empty Trash now! Maybe my manipulations caused it to get a legal size path? Most bizarre thing I have seen on MacOS, and I started with the original 512K Mac!  Any explanation?